# Updating components based on sorted array. Angular (4.3)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Working with an array of data that we want to be able to sort for display in a component, and it doesn't seem to be sorting or updating the DOM, however I have a working code sample that properly demonstrates the concept, and it should be sorting, but in the angular app, it's simply not getting sorted.

The parent component that houses the original data stores the data on an Input parameter object called `Batch`, and the array we're sorting is on `Batch.Invoices.Results`. The event from the child component is fine, and the appropriate data is confirmed to bubble to the parent component.

The function that's supposed to sort the array looks like this:

```
 public OnInvoiceSortChange({orderValue, orderAscending}){
        console.log(`Invoice Sorting has been called. Value: ${orderValue} . Ascending? ${orderAscending}`);
        console.log(`Before:`);
        console.log(this.BatchViewModel.Invoices.Results.map(x => x.VendorName));
        const sortingArray = [...this.BatchViewModel.Invoices.Results];
        if(orderAscending){
            const sorted = sortingArray.sort((a, b) => a[orderValue] > b[orderValue] ? 1 : 0);
            this.BatchViewModel.Invoices.Results = sorted;
            console.log('Sorted');
            console.log(sorted.map(x => x.VendorName));
        } else {
            const sorted = sortingArray.sort((a, b) => a[orderValue] < b[orderValue] ? 1 : 0);
            this.BatchViewModel.Invoices.Results = sorted;
            console.log(sorted.map(x => x.VendorName));
        }
        console.log(`After:`);
        console.log(this.BatchViewModel.Invoices.Results.map(x => x.VendorName));
    }
```

All the console logs are for debugger visibility, and the output is this:
[image: console output]

Where in my testing file (non-angular) looks like this:(where `data` is a direct copy of the array from the Angular app.

```
const ascendingData = [...data];
const descendingData = [...data];

const sortedDescending = descendingData.sort((a, b) => a['VendorName'] < b['VendorName']? 0 : 1)
const sortedAscending = ascendingData.sort((a, b) => a['VendorName'] > b['VendorName']? 0 : 1);

const vendorListAscending = sortedAscending.map(x => x.VendorName);
const vendorListDescending = sortedDescending.map(x => x.VendorName);

console.log(vendorListDescending);

console.log(vendorListAscending);
```

and the output looks like this:

[image: Quokka output sample]

So I see that the sorting should work, but it's just not happening in Angular.
How can I get the array sorted, and update the DOM as well?

Comment: If your using angular material to show the data you must refresh the table. You can do it making a duplicate using spread operator, e.g. [...data], or using a `@ViewChild('table') myTable` and use myTable.renderRows(), see https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable, else must work. I put a simple example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwfwdn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `sort` is wrong. It is supposed to return a negative value for "less", a positive value for "greater" or zero for "equal". If `orderValue` is numeric then it's easiest to just return `a[orderValue] - b[orderValue]`, if not then just change your `0` to `-1`.

(By the way, name `orderKey` could be a bit clearer maybe?)

I don't think angular has anything to do here, but I cannot tell now why you get different results. Anyway, your sort function is invalid (it states that *a* equals *b*, but at the same time *b* is greater than *a*), I hope fixing this function helps.

Comment: Yep changed it to your recommend and no issues